# I need to go to task manager after every bootup to be able to interact with Windows

Tags: windows, boot, razer-keyboard, razer-mouse

This may sound weird, but every time I boot up my computer I need to hit CTRL-ALT-DEL and open task manager otherwise I am unable to interact with Windows. I can't click buttons, hit the start button, hit task bar icons, nothing, yet Windows appears to be operating fine (not frozen, startup programs still popping up).

It does not seem like any weird OS issue as I have had the problem when trying Windows 8.1, Windows 8, as well as going down and trying Windows 7 32 bit, and Windows 7 64 bit.

It seems to become a problem after installing Windows updates which includes some driver updates. I think it may have to do with the Razer updates for my Razer keyboard and mouse. One of the Windows updates includes adding the Razer Synapse program and likely also updates drivers related to it.

What exactly is going wrong here? It doesn't make sense how opening task manager fixes the problem. It is getting annoying to have to do this on every boot up.

Comment: You have system corruption and/or a program that is configured to start when your user profile is logged into.  To determine which, boot to a absolute minimum start-up configuration and verify if the problem still exists.

Comment: @Ramhound Before I do Windows update on a fresh install the problem is not present.

Comment: I don't understand that comment.  If you suspect the Razer drivers, do what I suggest, that will confirm if it is indeed the problem.

Comment: By the way you can open the task manager directly with CTRL+SHIFT+ESC..
So if you think Razer drivers are the problem, have you tried a fresh windows install without installing these drivers ?

Comment: @Ramhound I am more looking to find out why they could be causing such an issue

Comment: @Swe I think I may try to uninstall/revert the driver install for them and see if that does anything.

Comment: @Fogest - When you confirm the drivers are the problem I will explain the reason, until you do that, I won't explain the reason. If I don't know what is causing the problem with 100% certainty, I can't explain the reason, and doing so prematurely makes a horrible answer.

Comment: @Ramhound It appears the standard Windows drivers are still in use: http://i.imgur.com/7ezgTNJ.png

Comment: @Swe looking in my device manager it looks like they are still using the stock Windows Drivers http://i.imgur.com/7ezgTNJ.png

Comment: @Swe also it needs to be CTRL+ALt+DEL then task manager. Going straight to task manager does not fix it.

Comment: You should try with another mouse and keyboard. If they work, it confirms that your Razer hardware/driver is causing the problem.

Comment: Also I've found a lot of users using Synapse (Razer software) having problems. Try maybe to update your keyboard firmware as described at the bottom of this [page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/problem-solved-razer-synapse-20-software-was-cause/4e2534c9-9aeb-4a8b-97ea-0b370350d4d5).

Comment: The firmware update fixed the issue. The firmware updater even warned me that the device version is the same as the updater's version but let me ignore the warning and continue. I guess it may have had that same version but maybe the drivers given by Windows are not installing correctly or something. Problem solved now!